# javascript text match count and regex spaces not work

Tags: javascript, regex, match, whitespace

i have a ploblem. im genereting a small scipt for text matches cont and ordering match counts.
[click to see jsfiddle live example](http://jsfiddle.net/9hcL8/)

my example scripts :

```
var testtext1 = "apple banana and kiwi pineapple juice";
var testtext2 = "need apple banana pineapple milkshake";
var testtext3 = "apple pineapple lower prices";
var testtext4 = "only apple banana kiwi pineapple lovers";
var testtext5 = "kiwi pineapple apple banana sales";

alert(testtext1.match(/apple banana kiwi|apple banana|apple|banana|kiwi/gi).length); //3 matches
alert(testtext2.match(/apple banana kiwi|apple banana|apple|banana|kiwi/gi).length); //2 m
alert(testtext3.match(/apple banana kiwi|apple banana|apple|banana|kiwi/gi).length); //2 m
alert(testtext4.match(/apple banana kiwi|apple banana|apple|banana|kiwi/gi).length); //2 m
alert(testtext5.match(/apple banana kiwi|apple banana|apple|banana|kiwi/gi).length); //3 matches
```

text1= only 3 matches why ? watch regex

apple banana kiwi OR apple banana OR apple OR banana OR kivi

apple banana kiwi NO match 0

apple banana YES match 1

appple YES match 2

banana YES match 3

kiwi YES match 4

okay why return 3 matches not 4 matches ?? and other examples ?

[image: see matchs this pic ?]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at below demo

[Live DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/hK2hJ4/7)

surround it by word boundary otherwise `pineapple` will be matched by `apple`

```
\b(apple banana kiwi|apple banana|apple|banana|kiwi)\b
```

Matches

```
apple banana and kiwi pineapple juice        2
need apple banana pineapple milkshake        1
apple pineapple lower prices                 1
only apple banana kiwi pineapple lovers      1
kiwi pineapple apple banana sales            2
```

---

#### EDIT

If you change the order then the result will be something different

```
\b(apple|banana|apple banana kiwi|apple banana|kiwi)\b
```

[Live DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/hK2hJ4/8)

```
apple banana and kiwi pineapple juice        3
```

Comment: I'm sorry I do not understand the logic of this match. Please wait a moment I'll add a picture to tell.

Comment: Thank you. After matching a word once again understood that match together.

Comment: Keep short words first in the group. `\b(kiwi|apple|banana|apple banana|apple banana kiwi)\b` but that condition will never be caught because `apple` is already captured hence there is no chance for `apple banana` and `apple banana kiwi` hence there is no use of extra words. Keep largest(bigger) words first in the group to match it first. Rest depends on your choice.